# how to save jpa lists of list

Tags: arraylist, spring-data-jpa, entity

I want to save list of list data in my spring project

my project front is vue

front send data strcuture like it

```
 data=[[{}],[{},{}],[{},{}]]
```

This is my Data

```
"option1": [
    {
        "firstOption": "s",
        "quantity": 1,
     
        "option2": [
            [
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "ss",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 10,
                
                    "monthlyPayment": 4412,
                    "total": 158832,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                  
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                },
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "ss",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 11,
                   
                    "monthlyPayment": 4412,
                    "total": 158832,
                    "prePayment": "0",
               
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "dd",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 10,
                   
                    "monthlyPayment": 88,
                    "total": 3168,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                },
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "dd",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 11,
                 
                    "monthlyPayment": 88,
                    "total": 3168,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                 
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "f",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 10,
                    "monthlyPayment": 4412,
                    "total": 158832,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                },
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "f",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 11,
                   
                    "monthlyPayment": 4412,
                    "total": 158832,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                }
            ]
        ],
        "itemIdx": 165
    },
    {
        "firstOption": "aa",
        "quantity": 1,

        "option2": [
            [
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "sdf",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 10,
                    
                    "monthlyPayment": 1000000,
                    "total": 1000000,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                },
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "sdf",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 11,
                   
                    "monthlyPayment": 1000000,
                    "total": 1000000,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "ee",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 10,
                    
                    "monthlyPayment": 25885,
                    "total": 931860,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                   "used": true    
                },
                {
                    "optionsDetail": "ee",
                    "leaseType": "1",
                    "needType": 11,
                  
                    "monthlyPayment": 25885,
                    "total": 931860,
                    "prePayment": "0",
                    "state": "-",
                    "used": true    
                }
            ]
        ],
        "itemIdx": 108
    }
```

I want to save using spring data jpa

one way is

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "opt_idx" )
private List<RentTypeList> option2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

other
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List option2 = new ArrayList<>();

I use two way But ther are occur error

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `EntityList` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
    Cannot deserialize instance of `option2` out of START_ARRAY token
    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 9, column: 13] (through reference chain:
    EntityList["option1"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->option2["option2"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
```

How to i change ?

Comment: First thing is there is a mismatch between data you send and the field mapping.
According to your data the field "option2" should be   "private List<List<RentTypeList>> option2 = new ArrayList<>();"

Comment: And second thing is you cannot save List<List<>>  directly like how you are mapping.
You need to use one more Class in between.  But what exactly is the neccesity to have some model like this is the question you should ask.